# Why is this function not holomorphic on a disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the complex-valued functions

$$f_1\left(z\right)=Erf\left(R-z\right)$$

and

$$f_2\left(z\right)=Erf\left(R-\lvert z\rvert \right)$$

Now, I'm told $f_1$ is holomorphic over the disk of radius $R$ (in fact it's an "entire" function), but $f_2$ isn't. Can anyone explain why this?

I imagine $f_1$ satisfies the Caucy-Riemann equations, though I'm not sure how to break it down into its real and imaginary parts (perhaps by looking at Eq. 11 in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1973-27-122/S0025-5718-1973-0326991-7/S0025-5718-1973-0326991-7.pdf)?) in order to take the necessary partial derivatives.

Can I argue that $f_2$ doesn't satisfy the CR equations because its imaginary part is always equal to 0 since we take the modulus of $z$ (while its real part has a non-zero first derivative)?

Comment: The Error function isn't the problem. Is the modulus a holomorphic function?

Comment: $z = x + iy$ in the usual sense

Comment: Yes, but is the modulus, $f(x,y)=|u(x,y)+i v(x,y)|$, holomorphic?

Comment: no, only at the origin (are the CR equations satisfied). So this implies the whole function is not holomorphic?

Comment: It's a more subtle matter. You can write $|z|^2=\bar z z$, and you can also write the Cauchy Riemann conditions for any complex function $f$ as $\partial f / \partial \bar z = 0$. If you applied this to $|z|^2$, however, you'd get $z$, not $0$, on any open set. So it fails the CR conditions everywhere!

Comment: No real-valued function is analytic in any connected open set unless it's constant there. Since $f_2$ is real-valued and nonconstant in any open set, it is not analytic in any open set.